# How to create a function in R to categorize numeric variables, that will make different categories for different variable?

Tags: r

I want to categorize the variable based on percentile. I wrote this code but after categorization Q3 is missing from the dataset! Even Q1, Q2 and Q4 are not classifies correctly!

```
quart_cat <- function(x,y){
     Q1 <- quantile(x[,y], 0.25)
     Q2 <- quantile(x[,y], 0.50)
     Q3 <- quantile(x[,y], 0.75)
     for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
         if (x[i,y] <= Q1){
         x[i,y] <- paste(colnames(x)[y], sep = '-', "Q1")
         }
         else if (x[i,y] <= Q2){
         x[i,y] <- paste(colnames(x)[y], sep = '-', "Q2")
         } 
         else if (x[i,y] <= Q3){
         x[i,y] <- paste(colnames(x)[y], sep = '-', "Q3")
         }
         else{
         x[i,y] <- paste(colnames(x)[y], sep = '-', "Q4")
         }
     }
     return(x)
 }
```

Comment: Could you please share some example data that we can use to reproduce the issue? Right now you say it does not classify correctly, but it's not clear what exactly the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `cut` function:

```
quart_cat <- function(x, y){
  cut(x[, y], quantile(x[,y]), paste0(colnames(x)[y], "-Q", 1:4), include.lowest = T)
}
```